# CSS3 Scale Flicker in Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, scale

I am experiencing an issue with CSS3 scaling and Safari (v10.0.1).

I have a selection of grid items with the following structure:

```
<div class="grid-inline col-12 bp1-col-6 bp3-col-3 index-grid-selector index">
    <a href="">
        <div class="index-grid-item">
            <div class="index-grid-dummy"></div>
            <img srcset=", 2x" title="" alt="">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS (LESS):

```
.index-grid-selector {      
    a {     
        .index-grid-item {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;

            .index-grid-dummy {
                padding-bottom: 100%;
            }

            img {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;  
                -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; 
                -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;  
                transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; 
            }
        }
    }

    &:hover {
        .index-grid-item {
            img {
                transform: scale(1.2);
                -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;  
                -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; 
                -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;  
                transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The image is positioned absolutely within the grid item container and then scaled on hover.

During the image scaling in Safari, the image enlarges slightly and appears to shift. Gaps (white lines) appear around the image. Once the animation is complete, the image sits correctly, until the hover function is removed.

I have set up a working demo here to showcase the issue.

http://www.testdomainone.co.uk/test.html

I have tried applying the folowing to the image and its parent, but the issue still occurs.

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)
```

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you attempted -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; or the following two together? -webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Comment: @LucasCordina I already have backface visibility added, but have just tried this along with perspective and unfortunately no change.

Comment: Try with changing `transition: all` to `transition: transform`

Comment: @LGSon Thanks, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve your specific issue using an `img` tag, though since you use fixed size for your images, why not use `background-image`

*Updated with [`image-set`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#image-set-notation) to achieve the equivalent for background images as `srcset` does for `img` ... and since it is more or less only iOS Retina which use that high resolution, it will be a decent fallback for browser not supporting it*

```css
.index-grid-item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.index-grid-dummy {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.index-grid-item:hover > div {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-grid-item">
  <div class="index-grid-dummy" style="background-image: -webkit-image-set( url(http://www.testdomainone.co.uk/images/uploads/tours/39/jmc_5233-bigsur__thumb_large.jpg) 1x, url(http://www.testdomainone.co.uk/images/uploads/tours/39/jmc_5233-bigsur__thumb_large_2x.jpg) 2x );
background-image: url(http://www.testdomainone.co.uk/images/uploads/tours/39/jmc_5233-bigsur__thumb_large.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

*Side note, in above sample I use inline style to set the image source in the markup, as one does with the `img` tag, and of course this could be set in the CSS as well*

Comment: Thank you, but I am infact using srcset for the images. I just simplified the code for this demo purpose.

Comment: @ccdavies You could use [`image-set`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#image-set-notation) to achieve the equivalent for background images ... and since it is more or less only iOS Retina which use that high resolution, it will be a decent fallback for browser not supporting it ... updated my answer using `image-set`

Comment: Thanks, but due to the nature of the site, retina optimised images need to be displayed to all. As Edge and Firefox aren't supported at all, I can't use this solution.